# Excel auto sort rows?

Tags: microsoft-excel, sorting

I know how to sort rows given their value, however as I keep adding new rows the values keep changing and I would like Excel to auto sort every thing I add something. On sheet 1 I have a table like this:

```
    TEAM 1   TEAM 2   TEAM 3
1    3        3        1
2    1        1        0 
3    0        3        0
4    3        3        0
5    3        1        1
```

Whereas on sheet 2 I have this:

```
         TOTAL
TEAM 1    10
TEAM 2    11
TEAM 3    2
```

Sheet2 is using a formula like this: `=SUM(Sheet1!B:Sheet1!B)`

The idea is that this table should be sorted out automatically every time I add a new row on sheet 1. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. To avoid confusion, please only ask one question per post. Now, to your main question; you are not sorting, you are totaling the sum of the columns by Team. Please provide the formula you are using to SUM the total on sheet 2. We can then help you from there.

Comment: So what you are expecting is the table on Sheet2 should automatically update when you add new rows to Sheet1? Is that correct? Is the workbook set to auto calculate?

Comment: Yes, and I guess is not set.

Answer (score 0):

This macro not only sort, it also makes the SUM:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Dim wkb As Workbook
    Set wkb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim wks, wks1 As Worksheet
    Set wks = wkb.Worksheets("Sheet1") ' Sheet with the results
    Set wks1 = wkb.Worksheets("Sheet2") ' Sheet with the totals
    wks1.Rows.Clear ' Clear the contents of Sheet2
    wks1.Cells(1, 2) = "TOTAL"
    usedcolumns = True
    thecolumn = 1
    totalrow = 2
    While usedcolumns
        therow = 1
        totalpoints = 0
        usedrows = True
        While usedrows
            thedata = wks.Cells(therow, thecolumn)
            If thedata <> "" Then
                If therow = 1 Then
                    teamname = thedata
                Else
                    totalpoints = totalpoints + thedata
                End If
                therow = therow + 1
            Else
                usedrows = False
                If therow = 1 Then usedcolumns = False
            End If
        Wend
        If teamname <> "" Then
            wks1.Cells(totalrow, 1) = teamname
            wks1.Cells(totalrow, 2) = totalpoints
            teamname = ""
            totalpoints = 0
            thecolumn = thecolumn + 1
            totalrow = totalrow + 1
        End If
    Wend
    lastrow = wks1.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    With wks1
        .Range("A1:B" & lastrow).Sort key1:=.Range("B2:B" & lastrow), order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes
    End With
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Go to VBA /Macros with alt+ F11 and double click `Sheet1`, then paste this code on the right side.

To avoid any potential problem that may arise if someday the macro causes an error, blocking the event detection on the workbook, double click on `This Workbook` and paste this:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
   Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I am trying your macro now. Do I need to press anything after I paste the codes? Nothing is happening on my sheets.

Comment: Change or add or remove a value on `Sheet 1` and `Sheet 2` will change.

Comment: Nothing happens. Sorry, I know I am doing something wrong. The Sheet2 must be completely clean?

Comment: When you pasted the code, did you previously double clicked `Sheet 1`?

Comment: It doesn't matter if `Sheet 2`is clear or not.

Comment: You mean on the VBA /Macros window? I did.

Comment: I changed the code to easily reference to the sheets in the lines  `Set wks = wkb.Worksheets("Sheet1") ` and  `Set wks1 = wkb.Worksheets("Sheet2")`. Paste the code, check that you put the code of the `Workbook`. Save, close, open again, activate macros and it should work.

Comment: No, sorry. I got nothing. I created a new excel file from scratch. On sheet1 I used columns A B C D and rows from 1 to 6. The first row is just the header with the team names. The first cell is blank. I inserted the values from A2 to D6. I opened up the VBA /Macros window and double clicked on Sheet1. I pasted the first long code you gave me. I then clicked on "this workbook" and pasted the second one. I saved my file. I changed the value of a cell but still nothing happens. I have Excel 2010 by the way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31136/discussion-between-jcbermu-and-cain-nuke).